Why rollupOptions.output.compact would cause Vite build error on Chrome 62?
Vite config: build.rollupOptions.ouput.compact: true.
imoport.meta.url is used in the project.
npm run build

npm run preview

preview on Chrome 62，there is an error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined

If I remove compact config or set compact false, there would be no error.

try IE6 better...
